# Changing ListBoxItem Height while using MahApps.Metro

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mahapps.metro

I have a project which uses MahApps.Metro.

In code behind of a ListBox I temporarily make the height of a `ListBoxItem` to 0.

```
 Dim draggedItemContainer As UIElement = Helper.GetItemContainerFromPoint(itemsControl, _dragStartPosition)

            If draggedItemContainer IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim lbi As ListBoxItem = CType(draggedItemContainer, ListBoxItem)
                lbi.Height = 0
            End If
```

Without using MahApps.Metro it works fine. Is there something special here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MetroListBoxItem` style of [MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) sets the `MinHeight` to `25`, so you must set this also to `0`.